# Simple Windows Form Not Showing

Tags: forms, visibility, show

I cobbled together some code that iterates through all of my directories on all my drives searching for files that match a criteria.  I was hoping to document my search progress while it processed each of the directories by writing the filenames of matching files onto a simple Windows Form ("textBox1.Text = fi1.FullName;"); however the form does not become visible until the search has completed.  Although I suspect that the Window form is inactive until the end of the search (so writing to it is ineffective), I'm not certain what to do to make the form visible during the search.  May I ask if someone could take a moment and look at the code and advise me?

Thank you for your help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FindFiles
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var searchPattern = ".jpg";
            var matchedFiles = FindMatchingFiles(searchPattern);
        }

        private List<string> FindMatchingFiles(string searchPattern)
        {
            var l = new List<string>();
            var allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

            foreach (var d in allDrives.Where(d => d.IsReady))
            {
                foreach (var file in GetFiles(d.Name)) 
                {
                    if (!file.EndsWith(searchPattern)) continue;
                    var fi1 = new FileInfo(file);
                    textBox1.Text = fi1.FullName;
                    l.Add(file);
                }
            }
            return l;
        }

        static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path)
        {
            var queue = new Queue<string>();
            queue.Enqueue(path);
            while (queue.Count > 0)
            {
                path = queue.Dequeue();
                try
                {
                    foreach (var subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
                    {
                        queue.Enqueue(subDir);
                    }
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }
                string[] files = null;
                try { files = Directory.GetFiles(path); }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }
                if (files == null) continue;
                foreach (var t in files) { yield return t; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your search code is running in the UI thread.  The UI won't be updated until your search code completes.

Take a look at BackgroundWorker and its ReportProgress mechanism to execute long running code without blocking the UI.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx may help.

Comment: Perfect solution JSR. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at asynchronous programming with
[async and await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).  Let your search happen in a different thread.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx